# Android not executable 64-bit

Tags: android, adb, fuzzing

I'm trying to follow this https://blog.quarkslab.com/android-greybox-fuzzing-with-afl-frida-mode.html and fuzz some app on my SM-A500FU. I rooted the device, followed every step (I hope) in the guide and when I try to execute the fuzzer with ./afl-fuzz I have the following error

./afl-fuzz: not executable: 64-bit ELF file

But the file is executable: -rwxrwxrwx shell    shell     1247296 YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM afl-fuzz

The file is compiled for arm64-v8a which is the architecture of my device. afl-fuzz: ELF 64-bit LSB pie executable, ARM aarch64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /system/bin/linker64, BuildID[sha1]=48d58efd77335135c21df48899f297dff3b75d90, with debug_info, not stripped

How can I solve?

I also tried to compile the file for other ABIs (armeabi-v7a) but not worked, I also got some strange errors during make.

I literally followed the guide, done same steps, don't know what I missed. I also seen some other issues for Android executable errors but the solution is totally different for my problem.

Comment: How have you copied the executable to the phone and where have you stored it? Most locations are marked as non-executable like `/sdcard/`. In those locations it doesn't matter what file permissions are set of if the CPU architecture matches,  Android simply won't execute anything for there.

Comment: Yes my phone is rooted and the executable file afl-fuzz is in /data/local/tmp. As you can see from above, the file has running permissions on the phone